# imagepng generate black image background

Tags: php, gd, gdlib, imagecreatefrompng

Below is my image generate code:

```
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight) or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream'); 
    print_r($thumb);
    $source = imagecreatefrompng($filename) or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream'); 
    print_r($source);
    imagecopyresampled($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);
    @imagepng(  $thumb, $original_img_dir_absolute_path.$original_img_name, 0 );
```

it will generate first png but with black background only.
anybody have idea about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to be OK. You may check if the fragment does not take a black part of the original image. You can also try to remove your "quality" parameter of `imagepng()` :

```
imagepng($thumb, $original_img_dir_absolute_path . $original_img_name);
```

Maybe your original image have a low contrast, and the low quality shows you a black image.

Comment: tthanks syscall, yes there is some problem with image quality

Comment: I removed the 'quality' parameter and it worked. But my function were generating a plain/text type file instead of my thumbnail... Any idea why? Can't find a explanation for this.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro, if you're getting your image from a webserver, you probably should add the appropriate headers before to send it. Ex, in PHP, `header("Content-Type: image/png")`.

Comment: @Syscall Hello. Thanks for replying! I used to use that header, but I removed for two reasons: i) I Didn't want to show the image, only generate and upload it; ii) that line were giving me black screen. Now I think something else were not right.